# Source Forge: no more opensource web scripts?

Tags: open-source

Not sure if this is off-topic, but I remember SourceForge.net used to be a big repository of open source website scripts/software.

You could usually find a script to accomplish anything you wanted, or at least edit something that already existed.

Today, it looks like Source Force only distributes desktop applications.

Is this true?

What are alternative open source web application repositories?

Comment: I see HotScripts.com still exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is the number of new open source repositories that have emerged in the last few years and SF seems to be following behind. I personally have my software listed on SF but since SF doesn't really support Bazaar, I have the code (and most of the project) hosted on Launchpad. You might be thinking that the majority of projects on SF are desktop programs from the homepage, but if you dig deeper you will see there are web applications hosted on SF as well (http://sourceforge.net/directory/internet/www/)

As for your question of alternative open source repositories, here is my list:

- Launchpad
- Github
- Google code
- Microsoft CodePlex